# gitignore unable to ignore files under certain directories

Tags: eclipse, git, gitignore

How do I ignore all folders/files under audit directory?

I tried adding `**/audit` to .gitignore which is present in the root of my project. where .git is present but the file is still getting displayed in unstaged changes in eclipse. Is it because of the `-` in file name?

```
data/test/audit/portfolio-tnc/TEST-2019-04-22T03-20-31.json
```

Comment: In case you edit the `.gitignore` not with Eclipse, in the _Git Staging_ view hit the _Refresh_ button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is already tracked by git you have to remove it from git index

```
git rm --cached data/test/audit/portfolio-tnc/TEST-2019-04-22T03-20-31.json
```

This will not remove the file but git won’t track it anymore.

You can untrack a whole directory with

```
git rm -r --cached data/test/audit
```

Comment: `fatal: pathspec 'data/test/audit/portfolio-tnc/PORTFOLIO_TNC_REQ-2019-04-23T05-24-48.json' did not match any files` even though the the file is present in the path.

Comment: Is there any way I can untrack all the files and directory in `data/test/audit/` ?

Comment: `**/` is for any audit directory in any directory. audit directory is not in target directory.

Comment: And what about `**/audit/**`?

Comment: `rm -r --cached "data/test/audit"` and `**/audit/**/*` in `.gitignore` worked.

Comment: Actually I think **/audit should work too, shouldn’t it?

Comment: @JigarNaik I thought your question was about Git in Eclipse, not the command line Git which is another thing, right?

Comment: yes the question was on git eclipse only. The refresh did not work for me, the issue may be git started tracking these files which i wanted to ignore. so `rm -r --cached` did the job of untracking the files. and after that in eclipse also it stopped showing in unstaged changes.

Comment: @JigarNaik In Eclipse the _Untrack_ command is in the right-click menu _Team > Advanced_ (which works independent if you have the Git command line installed or not installed).

Comment: @howlger I found the option to untrack in eclipse now. Thanks !